# Get a recognized word's position and duration in seconds

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

I am trying to get a recognized word's position and duration in seconds. My approach

```
private void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result != null)
    {
        foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in e.Result.Words)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!word.Text.ToString().Contains("."))
                {
                    RecognizedAudio audio = e.Result.GetAudioForWordRange(word, word);
                    Console.WriteLine(" {0,-30} {1,-10} {2,-10}",
                      word.Text, audio.Duration.TotalSeconds, audio.AudioPosition.TotalSeconds);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ff)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(ff.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that I don't know how to get the total number of seconds from the start. Because input is a wavefile

```
_recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(wavefile);
```

So I need this:

```
totalseconds the word starts - duration of the word - word
```

Comment: My reply didn't solve the problem or the engine is unprecise as the words don't appear at the mentioned time and there is no constant offset.

Comment: You should be able to build the current start point from the sum of the durations of the previous words.

Comment: @EricBrown Doesn't work because of Pauses in between words.

Comment: What output are you getting (and what output are you expecting)?

Comment: @EricBrown Assuming it detects the word `entertainment` which occurs in `our entertainment sector shows us an interesting development` then the audioposition might be `shows us an`(as it's duration is about the duration of `entertainment`. If it occurs later in the wav file, for instance `"we love their entertainment" is what our customers should scream`, the audioposition might point at `love their ente`. That's what's meant by `no constant offset`. I think I need to work with `audio.AudioPosition.TotalSeconds` and `e.Result.Audio.AudioPosition.TotalSeconds` and something else to do it well.